# Get the name of a youtube video

Tags: xml, r, youtube

I need to get the name of a youtube video from the link.
Typically I can do something like this to for a wikipedia page:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
xpathSApply(doc,'//title',xmlValue)
```

but the following doesn't work for youtube:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuOBzWF0Aws", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

Gives error.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What about changing the `https` to `http`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XML` library cannot download secured links. You can use `RCurl` and `getURL` to download the file and then parse with the `XML` library or in this case ask for a non secure version (`http`):

```
library(XML)
appURL <- "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuOBzWF0Aws"
doc <- htmlParse(appURL)
sapply(doc['//*[@id="eow-title"]'], xmlGetAttr, name = "title")

> sapply(doc['//*[@id="eow-title"]'], xmlGetAttr, name = "title")
[1] "If Google was a Guy"
```

Comment: +1 Very much appreciate it. However not sure why you load RCurl here, you are not using it!

Comment: Is there a good reference where I can learn about the structure? e.g. what to do if I have to find out the date of the video posting??  I am very new to the html analysis

Comment: What do you mean by the structure? The xpaths?

Comment: I mean how to extract different elements. e.g. How to extract strong string from: `<p id="watch-uploader-info">
              <strong>Published on May 20, 2014</strong>
          </p>`

Comment: Use the xpath `'//*[@id="watch-uploader-info"]/strong'` and `xmlValue`

Comment: Much appreciated. Is there a tutorial where I can read about this systematically?? I am very new to this type of analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57186/discussion-between-shambho-and-jdharrison).